# Node.js Paypal Payout API ECONNREFUSED Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal

I try to use the [PayPal payout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/single-payout/#create-a-single-payout):

With this snippet:

```
 var sync_mode = 'true';

    paypal.payout.create(create_payout_json, sync_mode, function (error, payout) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("PayPal Error",error);
            //throw error;
        } else {
            res.json(payout);
        }
    });
```

And gets this Error:

```
PayPal Error { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 173.0.82.78:443]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '173.0.82.78',
  port: 443 }
```

Yesterday it worked perfectly, I didn't change something - what could cause the error?

Comment: Do you get a response in the body? The paypal REST API seems return more specific error responses in the body which help to indicate what the problem is.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors

Comment: Is your API key still working? Are you logged in?